# How to preserve all whitespace in an attribute using xquery?

Tags: xquery, saxon

I need to preserve all whitespace in an attribute, as in

```
<img src="images/some     image.jpg"/>
```

All the whitespace are significant to find the image.

I use the saxon processor to parse the xml with an expression like this:

```
declare boundary-space preserve;
string($mydoc/html/body/div/a/img/@src)
```

But the result is

```
images/some image.jpg
```

I hope that someone can help as it seems to be easy.

Alain

Answer (score 1):

Is that multiple spaces in your attribute, or a tab character? If it's a tab, the XML parser will automatically replace it with a single space (see "Attribute Value Normalization" in the spec).

If it's multiple spaces, the only way I can think that it would be replaced with a single space is if the attribute is defined in the DTD with a type other than CDATA - which seems unlikely.

Comment: it's multiple spaces. And I cannot change the way the attribute is coming as it is from tiers code.

Comment: The source document is a html document

Comment: Then how is it being parsed? Something like TagSoup? My guess would be that the parser is responsible for the whitespace normalization.

Comment: Then you might like to mark the question as answered, for the benefit of future visitors and the childish kudos of the answerer.

Answer (score 1):

aie aie aie !!!
The problem was not with the xquery processing.

In fact, I use Tidy to transform the html into xhtml before processing it by saxon.
And Tidy has the option literal-attributes set to false by default.

> This option specifies if Tidy should ensure that whitespace characters within attribute values are passed through unchanged.

Setting it to true resolve the problem and all the intermediate whitespace are preserved.

I'm sorry to have wasted your time